# How to turn a csv(or similar) to bmp(or similar)

Tags: csv, bmp, basic, smallbasic

I am currently doing a project in Microsoft Small Basic to have some fun, though I have got stuck.

I have an array that I can export to a file in any format, which uses bytes as its smallest thing, such as a csv.
Each pixel is a hex value, FFFFFF say, and it gets put into a file like:

```
FFFFFF,000000,FFF000,000FFF
000AAA,AAAAAA,AAA000,000000
```

etc...

Is there any way I could turn this into an image such as a bmp file or other raster format.

Comment: Not much - I looked around online to see csv to bmp converters but there arent any really.

Comment: So you have a single *specific task* and your research consisted of googling for a solution to exactly that *specific task*? Why not break it up into manageable parts, such as (1) read CSV, (2) create BMP?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could write out your image in NetPBM's `PPM` format which is extremely simple and documented on Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format).

So, for example the following (enlarged) 3x2 image:

[image]

would look like this (the part following `#` on each line is my comment):

```
P3                               # P3 means ASCII, 3-channel RGB
3 2                              # width=3, height=2
255                              # MAX=255, therefore 8-bit
255 0 0 0 255 0 0 0 255          # top row of pixels in RGB order
0 255 255 255 0 255 255 255 0    # bottom row of pixels in RGB order
```

Then you can use **ImageMagick**, which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows to make that into a BMP at the command line like this:

```
magick input.ppm output.bmp
```

or, if you want a JPEG with contrast stretch and resized to 800x600:

```
magick input.ppm -resize 800x600 -auto-level output.jpg
```

---

You can equally do the conversion with **GIMP**, **Adobe Photoshop**, probably **MS Paint**, probably **IrfanView**, or using the NetPBM toolkit. For example, with the NetPBM tools (which are **much lighter weight** than **ImageMagick**) the conversion would be:

```
ppmtobmp image.ppm > result.bmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Mark's fine answer, using ImageMagick and Unix scripting, one can do the following:

```
Convert your text file so as to replace commas with new lines, then add leading # to your hex values and store in an array (arr)

Then change each hex value into colors as rgb triplets in the range 0-255 integers with spaces between the 3 values and put into a new array (colors).

Find out how many rows and columns you have in your text file.

Then convert the array of colors into a PPM image and convert that image to bmp while enlarging to 300x200.
```

Here is the corresponding code:

```
arr=()
colors=()
arr=(`cat test.txt | tr "," "\n" | sed 's/^/#/'`)
num=${#arr[*]}
for ((i=0; i<num; i++)); do
colors[i]=`convert xc:"${arr[$i]}" -format "%[fx:round(255*u.r)] %[fx:round(255*u.g)] %[fx:round(255*u.b)]" info:`
done
numrows=`cat test.txt | wc -l`
numvalues=`cat test.txt | tr "," " " | wc -w`
numcols=`echo "scale=0; $values/$rows" | bc`
echo "P3 $numcols $numrows 255 ${colors[*]}" | convert - -scale 400x200 result.bmp
```

[image]

Note: I had to add a new line in the text file after your last color character, so that wc -l would compute the proper number of lines. That is the file must end with a new line character.